# Dropdown menu using CSS disappears when mouse is off the menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu created using css. Code below.

**CSS**

```
/* Navigation Menu Styles */

ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2  {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul#navmenu li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
 }

ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    line-height: 25px; 
    background-color: #171717;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #056000;              /* green */
}

ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0px;
}

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Social</a> <span class="d_arrow">&#9660;</span>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, I want to experiment the result of my dropdown menus.
I want to position the dropdown menus farther from its parent menu by changing the top position from 38px to 50px like:

```
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

But when I hover the mouse to its dropdown menus, it suddenly disappears. I know that something is wrong with my codes here like setting the position top. Can someone help me correct my code? Thanks

Comment: Seems to work fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kgah0osg/)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Try changing the postion top to 100px.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment the issue is when you change `top` to a big number. The OP  issue can't reproduce (like to change top to `50px`). The problem is when you add top(big number) then there will be an empty content between elements and `:hover` won't work. A fast solution will be to add `height` to `img` with class `.d_arrow` so image work like a "bridge" between the elements:

```css
/* Navigation Menu Styles */

ul#navmenu,
ul.sub1,
ul.sub2 {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul#navmenu li {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
ul#navmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: #171717;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
  background-color: #056000;
  /* green */
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
  display: block;
}
/*add this rule*/
span.d_arrow {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Social</a>  <span class="d_arrow">&#9660;</span>
    <ul class="sub1">
      <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Youtube</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Events</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. I just add some padding top on the ul#navmenu ul.sub1

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/b73a5fzo/)

```
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-top:12px;
}
```

and also few things added to make the design clean and put the down arrow inside the anchor tag

```
<li><a href="#">Social <span class="d_arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
```